# Difficulty in Obtaining an API key for Google Maps

Tags: android, api, google-maps, key

I am following the instructions in this tutorial https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/lectures/maps.pdf

I get the command prompt to C:\Users\USERNAME.android (for windows new)

I then type >keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore

but when I press Enter I get:

> [image]

What is going wrong? It seems like I have not set something up quite correctly, because I have followed the instructions which didnt seem difficult.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin is where keytool is. What does this mean?

Comment: you should add that folder to your system PATH variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Open Terminal In Android Studio you are running.
2. Enter: keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
3. Copy SHA1 key.
4. Go To Google developer console and select Android API Key.
5. Copy SHA1 key to android Fingerprint and Write Package in Package Name block.
6. Generate API key.
7. USE API key
```